# Can not use fsockopen to access Tor control port

Tags: php, sockets, port, tor

I installed Tor on my linux system and I'm trying to access control port which should be 9051 as set in config `/etc/tor/torrc` file:

```
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword 16:[PWD_HASH]
```

using PHP fsockopen():

```
fsockopen('127.0.0.1', 9051, $error_number, $err_string, 10);
```

But I'm getting this excetion `fsockopen(): Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:9051 (Connection refused)`.

So I checked:

```
$ sudo netstat -al | grep 905
tcp        0      0 localhost:9051          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

and

```
curl --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 https://check.torproject.org
```

Despite spending hours of googling I could not find why I'm getting this exception and I would appreciate some help.